# scons CheckCXX() false but compiler works

Tags: python, visual-studio, scons

I unistalled AVR Studio 6.4 and now:

```
if not conf.CheckCXX() :
    raise SCons.Errors.StopError("C++ compiler is not working")
```

Fails but if i outline this it compiles just fine. Anyone has a clue why it fails? (Got MSVS 14 running and it uses v140 to compile)

LOG:

```
scons: Configure: Checking whether the C++ compiler works... 
scons: Configure: ".sconf_temp\conftest_0.cpp" is up to date.
scons: Configure: The original builder output was:
  |.sconf_temp\conftest_0.cpp <-
  |  |
  |  |int main()
  |  |{
  |  |    return 0;
  |  |}
  |  |
  |
cl /Fo.sconf_temp\conftest_0.obj /c .sconf_temp\conftest_0.cpp /TP /nologo /O2 /DJIMDB_WINDOWS /DNDEBUG /DBOOST_UBLAS_NDEBUG /DJIMDB_NDEBUG
conftest_0.cpp
c1xx: fatal error C1083: Cannot open source file: '.sconf_temp\conftest_0.cpp': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Did you already have a look in the `config.log` that gets written out? Can you post its content?

Comment: adding the output, and it didnt add the output. the .sconf_temp is empty and deleting doesnt change anything.

Comment: and i havent changed anything else of the script.

Comment: Do an "scons -c", then remove the ".sconf_temp" folder and the complete ".sconsidg.dblite" file completely. Run "scons" again once, with the configure check for the CXX compiler active. Then paste the output of the new "config.log" to  your question (replace the old one).

Comment: this actually solved the issue, somehow there were some old temps i missed while deletion. thanks alot!